# Domain Users group is not getting for an active directory user

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

We are using the following code to get the groups of an active directory user.

```
StringCollection groups = new StringCollection();

try
{
   using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName, userName, password))
   {
      //find user roles
      UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, loginUserName);

      if (user != null)
      {
         DirectoryEntry de = (DirectoryEntry)user.GetUnderlyingObject();
         object obGroups = de.Invoke("Groups");                        

         foreach (object ob in (IEnumerable)obGroups)
         {
            DirectoryEntry obGpEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ob);                            
            groups.Add(obGpEntry.Name);
         }    
      }
   }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
```

This is working almost as expected. But while we checking the users with `Domain Users` group, the method didn't return the group name. Some users are only with this `Domain Users` group and while we calling this method for such users its returning an empty group.

Any suggestions please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a well-known and documented "omission" that the so called primary group is **not** returned from the `Groups` method in this code. There are some rather cryptic ways around this - or try this other approach:

if you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

if(user != null)
{
   // the call to .GetAuthorizationGroups() will return **all** groups that
   // user is a member of - including the primary group and all nested 
   // group memberships, too!
   var result = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

**Update:** if you insist on using the old legacy technology, check out [this blog post by Ryan Dunn](http://dunnry.com/blog/2005/01/18/DeterminingYourPrimaryGroupInActiveDirectoryUsingNET.aspx) which explains in great detail how to get the primary group for an AD account in C#.

Comment: yes, i have used this earlier, but then i got an error like "Information about the domain could not be retrieved (1355).". I can't figure out the cause, so i moved to use the old technique.

Comment: the given link is now showing 404 error http://dunnry.com/blog/2005/01/18/DeterminingYourPrimaryGroupInActiveDirectoryUsingNET.aspx%24

Comment: @mahesh: sorry, had an extra character in there after pasting - fixed, works now.

Comment: Thanks for the link.. but i didn't understand the things explained there. I am planning to use user.GetAuthorizationGroups(). But i didn't understand why i am getting that exception.. Can you please advice any solution for this.

Comment: thanks for this link.. i got answer from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179858/can-you-find-an-active-directory-users-primary-group-in-c