# Search LDAP for user permissions with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to get some information from Active Directory with VB.NET.
I have the "primaryGroupID" of a user, which is 2096 in this case.
**How can I get, with VB.NET, the CN of this group?**

Ultimately, what I need to do is find a list of groups that a user belongs to (including groups that belong to another group). I already have a function that gets the main groups except for the primary group, and another function that returns the ID of the primary group. Both detailed below.

```
Public Function getUserGroups(ByVal Username)
    Dim grupos As New ArrayList()
    Try
        Dim Entry As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, ldapAdminUser, ldapAdminPass)
        Dim Searcher As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(Entry)
        Searcher.SearchScope = DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree
        Searcher.Filter = "(&(objectcategory=user)(SAMAccountName=" & Username & "))"
        Dim res As SearchResult = Searcher.FindOne

        For i = 0 To res.Properties("memberOf").Count() - 1
            grupos.Add(res.Properties("memberOf")(i).ToString)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Return grupos
End Function


Public Function GetUserPrimaryGroupID(ByVal user As String) As String
    Dim grupoID As String = ""
    Try
        Dim Entry As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, ldapAdminUser, ldapAdminPass)
        Dim Searcher As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(Entry)
        Searcher.SearchScope = DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree
        Searcher.Filter = "(&(objectcategory=user)(SAMAccountName=" & user & "))"
        Dim res As SearchResult = Searcher.FindOne

        For i = 0 To res.Properties("primaryGroupID").Count() - 1
            grupoID = (res.Properties("primaryGroupID")(i).ToString) 'Esto devuelve la ruta "CN" del grupo
            'grupoID = (res.Properties("primaryGroupID")(i).ToString)
            'Dim de As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + res.Properties("primaryGroupID")(i).ToString())
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Return grupoID
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a VBScript sample here - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297951.

Essentially the primary group ID is the RID (the last component of the SID) of a group. So to find the group, you concatenate the domain SID and the primary group ID together.

Comment: Thanks Brian for your reply. I didn´t know you could get it that way.
I tried the code they mention in the website and I could not find a way to make it work in VB.Net. I'm not very familiar with VBS.

Is there any other example to do this same thing in VB.NET? I also tried "translating" the code from VBS with no luck :(

Comment: Here's a C# sample - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179858/can-you-find-an-active-directory-users-primary-group-in-c

Comment: Hi again Brian. Your hint was defenitelly helpful! I'm still strugling with a problem because my functions work on a PC in the domain but they don´t on a PC that is not in the domain. Weird....

I'll post the code in VB.Net once I get it sorted so people can get it done. Thanks for your help, and if you know how to solve the domain problem, let me know! ^^

Comment: I'd expect the issue is either with credentials or how you're passing the server/search root info to the constructor of `DirectoryEntry`.